# How to do summation of rows based on where conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have dataset stored in excel in below format.

[image]

The query that I have writtten yeilds below result.

[image]

The query should return one row. Same happens if I input additional calculated columns. Hence if I add amount2, amount3 likewise, the number of rows increases by 4 (2 for each amount),totalling to 6 rows, out of which 3 rows will return NULL values.

Table structure, sample data and my query are mentioned below:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f8c9931554863583616d0f662230996

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Here you go!. Hope this helps. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0e49b

Comment: *"Hope this helps"* Not alot sorry *"Right now, my sql query returns the result in below format. "* Still the query is missing which produces the result in the question..... also it is not "totally" clear how CustomerID is there in the results as he sqlfiddle does not totally match up with the column names and data shown here..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use filter

```
having sum(sales) is not null
```

edit after your fiddle

```
select CustomerName,BillNo,  sum(Amount)
from [dbo].[MarginTemp]
where [Type] = 'A'
group by  customername,BillNo
```

after edit your today's

```
SELECT  
       MAT.BillNo,MAT.ServiceCategoryName, 
       'Sep-19' AS MonthName,
    SUM(case when MAT.ServiceCategoryName = 'Z-Net Revenue'
     then MAT.Amount else 0 end) AS Amount

FROM MarginTemp MAT

WHERE 
MAT.BillNo='A202019339291'
GROUP BY MAT.BillNo,
         MAT.ServiceCategoryName
         having SUM(case when MAT.ServiceCategoryName = 'Z-Net Revenue'
     then MAT.Amount else 0 end)>0
ORDER BY BillNo ASC;
```

your are getting  null in your query because you have used   `MAT.BillNo,MAT.ServiceCategoryName` in group by where only one ServiceCategoryName meets condition and for others it showing null

after discussion, I got the original issue

```
with cte as
(SELECT MAT.BillNo,
       ---MAT.ServiceCategoryName, 
       'Sep-19' AS MonthName
       ,  SUM( case when MAT.ServiceCategoryName='Z-NET Revenue' then MAT.Amount else 0 end) as AMOUNT
      , SUM( case when MAT.ServiceCategoryName='Internal Dr Visit Charges' then MAT.Amount else 0 end) as [Internal Dr Visit Charges]
      ,SUM( case when MAT.ServiceCategoryName='External Dr Visit Charges' then MAT.Amount else 0 end) as [External Dr Visit Charges]

FROM MarginTemp MAT
WHERE MAT.BillNo = 'A202019339291'

GROUP BY MAT.BillNo, 
         MAT.ServiceCategoryName
) select BillNo,MonthName,max(AMOUNT) as amt,
max([Internal Dr Visit Charges]) as [Internal Dr Visit Charges]
,max([External Dr Visit Charges]) as [External Dr Visit Charges]
from cte
group by BillNo,MonthName
```

Comment: Reason being I have applied Group by on Type in outer Query. This is because the sub query needs Type filter

Comment: With all respect but this is simply guessing overflow without seeing a example and SQL query which you are using @xorpower ..

Comment: @xorpower https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e7398699f4f0603efa028171c160733 do you find this ?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin: Question updated with dbfiddle.uk

Comment: @xorpower https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4763a39fed79067474aed307d80c1fd7

Comment: This works like a charm!! Thanks @ZaynulAbadinTuhin But amount is just one parameter. There are 6 other parameters. Do I need to add 6 other having conditions?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin :https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ef7d9e8f6d4c868745c235a8bad452bc

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin : As per the dbfiddle query (mentioned above) the "Internal Charges" are 0 where as it should be 2000 (see snapshot in question)

Comment: @xorpower provide your output as well

Comment: Current output is provided in dbfiddle url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201006/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-xorpower).

Answer (score 0):

Does your query look like this?

```
select customerid, customername, sum(sales)
from t
where subtype = 'A'
group by customerid, customername;
```

This should return only one row per `customerid`/`customername` combination, not multiple rows.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!!! Please refer to the updated question